# Number treatment on FrontEnd [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a text input where the user enters a number in the format he wants, but it must be parsed to backend keeping the a format that make sense for the user.

For example: the number "1200.33" can be written "1200.33", "1,200.33", "1.200,33" or even "1'200.33" and still be understanded by the backend.

Is there a way I can do this from the frontend?

Comment: What number should be "1,234"? Or "1.234"?

Answer (score 0):

If the server is supposed to respond with the same formatting, then this is something you'd want to implement on the backend. Otherwise, you can just use the below code in your submit handler on the frontend.

```js
const stringA = "1,200.33";
const stringB = "1'200.33";
const stringC = "1200.33";
const stringD = "1.200,33";


function convert(string) {
  if(RegExp(/(\d+\.\d+\,\d+)/).test(string)) string = string.replace(/\./g,"").replace(",",".");
  string = string.replace(/[,']/g,"")
  return parseFloat(string);
}
  
console.log(convert(stringA))
console.log(convert(stringB))
console.log(convert(stringC))
console.log(convert(stringD))
```

If there is a backend response that needs formatting, the server should receive the input as is, and convert it via the above method. Perform your evaluation, and compare the return against the original input to reformat it (the code for this would be more elaborate).

Comment: It works for this number format. But what if the number is "2,1" or "2.1"?